# Which VM image should I choose on Azure for publishing a web application?

Tags: azure

I'm using the "App Service" to host my web application. However my application depends on a 3rd party service which requires a static IP. From my investigation I see that I have two options to obtain a static outbound IP.

1-) App Service Environment, which is an expensive premium service

2-) Creating a Virtual Machine

On Azure portal, when I try to create a virtual machine a large list of VMs is displayed. When I select one of them even more options are displayed. Which one is the best for a middle-size web application? What size would be enough?

Comment: You have a 3rd option, which is to add IP-based SSL to your web application.  That would give you a dedicated IP address for your app and would avoid you having to manage a VM (your 2nd option) going forward.

Comment: Regarding VM size: That's not something that can be answered here (or anywhere, really) - the sizes are well-documented, and you need to pick one that your app works well with, based on your knowledge of your app.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to procure a VM to assign static IP for your Azure Website. You can get a static IP for your Azure Web Application. Steps are given below.

1) Make sure your Web App is in either Basic or Standard mode
2) Configure CNAME in DNS for your Web App
3) Create a self-signed SSL certificate
4) Upload an configure the certificate

for more details https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2014/05/05/how-to-get-a-static-ip-address-for-your-microsoft-azure-web-site/

Comment: This article is not about an outbound IP address, rather getting a static IP address which is bound to your MAWS